# Python Shell shortcuts

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I've just started learning python from scratch

I've installed 3.6 for windows

On the IDLE shell how can I get the shortcut for retyping what you previously executed (this is usually the up button)?

and also there is usually a drop down list for when you're typing something and python shows a list of what you might be about to type and you can select and it types it for you?

example:

thanks

Comment: Try `Alt+p` and have fun

Comment: anyway to make the shortcut as the up button? i'm really used to the up button and its faster, and I guess it would be nice to know how to edit shortcuts

Comment: @physicsnoob1000 You really should mark the answer you feel like was the best [as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2):

To get last command executed, use `alt+p`.

Otherwise, under the Options menu, go to Configure IDLE >> Keys, and set history-next/history-previous to the keys you wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

Press enter on the line you want to retype

**EDIT**

To show autocomplete window press TAB.

There's a default delay in 2 seconds. You can set popupwait to 0 in `Options->Configure IDLE->Extensions->AutoComplete`. Take into accout that you should restart you shell to activate new settings.

Comment: press TAB key for drop down list

Comment: Do you know how to make the drop down list automatic? thanks

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain how to make autocomplete window show immediately.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.6 on Windows, specifically.

- Shortcut to get what you typed previously: **Alt** + **P**
- To get auto completion: **Ctrl** + **space**

*Also, you can navigate the configuration for these Shortcut Keys in the Navigation bar.*

Answer (score 0):

All of the keybindings can be changed in `Options > Configure IDLE > Keys`. The ones in my answer are the default on Windows.

- Cycle commands backwards: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
- Cycle commands forwards: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

  - Alternatively, put cursor on a line you want to re-run and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

- Pop-up auto completion: <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>)

  - Alternatively, just set `Options > Configure IDLE > General > Completions Popup Wait` to 0, for the autocompletion to always come up automatically